# Numpy: Folding an array column-wise

Tags: python, numpy, fold

I have an n-dimensional boolean numpy array. How can I apply the logical AND operation between each of the columns. I want to get the number of rows that contain only ones.

Example:

```py
n = np.array([[0, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [0, 0],
              [1, 1]]
              )
```

Here, the result should be 2 because only the third and last row contain only ones.

This can be done via the `functools` module:

```py
from functools import reduce
np.sum(reduce(np.logical_and, n.T))
```

but is there a way to do it only with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions, using solely *Numpy* is:

```
np.sum(np.equal(n, 1).all(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.all(1)` to check `and` on each row then use np.sum() for counting like below:

```
>>> res = n.all(1)
>>> res
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True])

>>> res.sum()
2
```